# c# ASP MVC5 において任意のフォルダにJS ファイルを配置し cshtml ファイル内で使用したい。

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

下記のフォルダ構成があったとします。

任意のフォルダ名１
　┃
　┗任意のフォルダ名２
　　┃
　　┗任意のフォルダ名３
　　　┃
　　　┗コントローラ名
　　　　┃
　　　　┣Index.cshtml
　　　　┃
　　　　┗Index.js

Global.asax.cs の Application_Start 内で RazorViewEngine を生成し Index.cshtml の場所を RazorViewEngine に登録するする事で、任意の場所のビューを表示する事はできました。
上記のフォルダ構成例において Index.cshtml の中から Index.js を使用したいです。
Index.cshtml の @section header の中に

```
<script src="Index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

と記述して、javascript の外部ファイルをブラウザまで上手く届ける方法をご教授頂きたく
お願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。Index.js を IndexJS.cshtml に名前を変更します。
IndexJS.cshtml では script　タグで javascript のコード を囲います。
Index.cshtml の中で @Html.Partial("IndexJS") を記述します。
c言語で言う #include のようなイメージ
これで外部の javascript のファイルを任意のフォルダで使用できました。